# gsheets flutter how to add credentials

Tags: flutter, dart, google-sheets, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

Im trying to integrate flutter [gsheets](https://pub.dev/packages/gsheets) (A library for working with Google Sheets API v4.) it says to add

```
    const _credentials = r'''
  {
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "",
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "",
  "client_email": "",
  "client_id": "",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": ""
}
''';
// your spreadsheet id
const _spreadsheetId = '';
```

Here I'm not sure how to use this. I have enabled all APIs following the instructions as per the gsheets library documentation on getting started and steps on medium. unfortunately, I'm just not sure about where to get details.

Cant find much reference in the internet. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service account from Google, which will give you a json file with the credentials you're looking for. Google has posted some instructions here: [https://support.google.com/a/answer/7378726?hl=en][1]
[1]: https://support.google.com/a/answer/7378726?hl=en.

Make sure you're careful with these credentials and keep them private; they contain some information about your service account that you wouldn't want to share with the public.